# correct way to handle errors inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Currently, I'm trying to decide what pattern I should use while dealing with errors inside a Promise. For instance, I have the code below

```
promiseFunc()
.then(result => {

    console.info(`.THEN:: ${result}`)
})
.catch(error => {

    console.info(`.CATCH:: ${error}`)
})

function promiseFunc() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(() => {

            throw Error("setTimeout's callback error")
            resolve('resolution')           
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

What I can't get is what approach should be used to reject the Promise if a function inside it (setTimeout(), in my case) throws an Error. In other words, I need a rejection instead of an error, but the only idea that comes to my mind is to add a try/catch block and reject the Promise from the catch.

Comment: Seems like the right approach.

Comment: Is really no different than if you weren't using promises and needed to catch errors. So `try/catch` would be appropriate way to do it

Comment: @charlietfl Unless you program with `async`/`await`, you shouldn't need `try`/`catch` with promises

Comment: @Bergi point being that if error occurs inside the setTimeout shown it would need to be caught

Comment: @charlietfl Point being that this should never be allowed happen in the first place :-)

Answer (score 3):

> What approach should be used to reject the Promise if a function inside it (setTimeout(), in my case) throws an Error

An asynchronous callback must never throw an exception. Your function that you try to promisify (`setTimeout`) either throws a synchronous exception (which `new Promise` handles), or it calls the callback. In the callback you must call `resolve` or `reject`, and do so without throwing an exception.

If you want to do additional things in the callback (besides calling `resolve`/`reject`), things that could throw an exception: **don't**!

The `new Promise` should wrap only the immediate function that you want to promisify, nothing else. Do more things in `then` callbacks that are chained to the promise - `then` will handle exceptions in its callback just fine:

```
function promiseFunc() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
//             ^^^^^^^ nothing can go wrong in here
  }).then(() => {
    throw "setTimeout's callback error";
//  ^^^^^ here, it will lead to a rejection
    return "resolution";
  });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, I knew that my understanding was incorrect. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You clarified some things for me.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing an error in an asynchronous function, instead of rejecting the promise.

Change `throw Error("")` to `reject("")`:

```
promiseFunc()
  .then(result => {
    console.info(`.THEN:: ${result}`)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.info(`.CATCH:: ${error}`)
  })

function promiseFunc() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject("setTimeout's callback error")
      resolve('resolution')
    }, 1000)
  })
}
```

Or add a try-catch statement, and reject it in the catch block

```
setTimeout(() => {
  try {
    throw new Error("setTimeout's callback error")
  } catch(error) {
    reject(error)
  }
  resolve('resolution')
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. This case is just a simplified version of the real case - if I'd have a function that _really_ can throw an error instead of my
   throw Error("setTimeout's callback error")
- how should I deal with that?
P.S. Just saw your updated response - so, I think that I have to use try/catch in my case

Answer (score 0):

Resolve, Reject and Error are three distinct things and your code need to handle cases when you need to resolve and when you need to reject it. If the condition you want is full-filled then you call the resolve method, with the condition can't be full-filled then call the reject() method.

In case of any errors thrown by your code or any other reason the single catch() block in the end of chain would be executed.

```
// doAsyncOperation1() returns a promise.
doAsyncOperation1()
.then(() => {
  // ...
  // doAnotherAsyncOperation() returns a promise
  // which will be inserted into the chain.
  return doAsyncOperation2();
})
.then((output) => {
  // output will be the value resolved by the
  // promise which was returned from doAsyncOperation2()
  // ...
  return doAsyncOperation3();
})
.catch((err) => {
  // Handle any error that occurred in any of the previous
  // promises in the chain.
});
```